# In datagrid click on cell combobox is (edititemtempalate) not coming

Tags: c#, wpf

I am Binding datagrid with Dictonary values.Now i am trying to click on cell Cpmbobox should come and update the value based comboxbox selected value.
Here when i click on datagrid cell i am getting Edititem is not allowed for this view double click

I have tried somany articles it's not worked for me.and i tried IsReadonly="True" for what ever required column for combobox.it was not worked.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="__fieldGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"  AllowDrop="True" Drop="__fieldGrid_Drop" PreviewDrop="__fieldGrid_PreviewDrop">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="(From)Source table column" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="22" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="(To)Service input field" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Key}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


Dictionary<string, string> _MappingData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _MappingData = _maps.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<MappedColumn, string, string>
                (x => x.To.ToString(),
                x => ((x.From != null && x.To != null && x.From.ToString() == x.To.ToString()) ? x.From.ToString() : "...")
                );
             __fieldGrid.ItemsSource = _MappingData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a collection that implements the `IList` interface for you to be able to edit the items.

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not implement `IList` and is thus not supported.

Comment: Thanks for your response to me.now it's working .i just added __fieldGrid.ItemsSource = _MappingData.ToList(); while binding.

Comment: Yes. This sets the `ItemsSource` to a `List<T>` which does implement `IList`.